# scroll a layout with a listview android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, scrollview

My problem is that i have my listview working perfect on a absoulteLayout but the buttons on the bottom aren't show up! I put a scrollview with a absoluteLayout with all items (textview, button, etc) and outside of the scrollview I put the listview, this didn't work, either, just scroll the buttons but the listview just move a little bit, how can I put a scrollview to can see the buttons on the button and make the listview works?
my XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!-- The main content view -->

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Ab">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="317dp"
            android:layout_height="429dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_x="45dp"
            android:layout_y="41dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This Works Monica!!"
            android:id="@+id/TV1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_x="120dp"
            android:layout_y="22dp" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Play :D"
            android:id="@+id/TESTME"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_x="190dp"
            android:layout_y="520dp" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Pause"
            android:id="@+id/PAUSE"
            android:layout_x="110dp"
            android:layout_y="521dp" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:text="Lista"
            android:id="@+id/LISTA"
            android:layout_x="274dp"
            android:layout_y="520dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lista?"
            android:id="@+id/CHECARL"
            android:layout_x="267dp"
            android:layout_y="490dp"
            android:checked="false" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="BorrarL"
            android:id="@+id/BORRARL"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="520dp" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#E6E6E7" />
```

Comment: use `RelativeLayout` as your parent view, put your buttons at the bottom of the relativelayout with alignparentBottom to true and place your listview above the buttons..safe to say put your buttons in a linearLayout and put your listview on top, hope you get the idea. sorry for silly errors

Comment: If you are unsure of layouts in Android have a read of the documentation. As there are so many screen sizes it is vital that you use relative layouts! so your gui design is dynamic and works across as many devices as possible! Have a read of the relative layout doc...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **absolute layout** that means, from documentation:

> A layout that lets you specify exact locations (x/y coordinates) of its children.

So if you don't see the buttons it is because they are positioned outside of your device screen bounds. And their position is **absolute** / **fixed** so they stay there no matter what.

I would recommend to **change to different layout.** I don't know what kind of app you are building but absolute layout is generally not the best choice.

Comment: i rather use a absolutelayout because I can move the items anywhere I want, but this isn't working right now, I have already changed it to relative and it works, is difficult for me to move  the items in that layout but at least it works!, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possibility number one:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/background"
                android:clickable="true">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/allPaymentListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addNewPayment"

        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addNewPayment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/primary_button_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
        android:text="@string/add_new_card"
        android:textColor="@color/light_blue"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

In this case the button will be always seen on the bottom of the page, below the listview.

The second possibilty is to add a footer to the listview:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)

In that case the view with the button will be the last element in the listview.

And don't use Absolute Layout it is deprecated, the reason is the app will not scale to different screen sizes as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a RelativeLayout with the buttons at the bottom and the ListView placed on top of the buttons.

AbsoluteLayout is, in general. to be avoided for layouts unless you are trying to accomplish a very specific purpose. It's considered an anti-pattern to position elements absolutely. To achieve what you have stated, a RelativeLayout would be the way to go.